# How can I refer to the low / high price of a security?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Let's say I have used request.security("SPX", timeframe.period, close)
Is there a way to refer to the high and low price of that security, or do I have to use extra requests to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`security()` supports tuples so you can pass multiple variables to your `security()` call.

```
[spx_open, spx_close, spx_high, spx_low] = request.security("SPX", timeframe.period, [open, close, high, low])
```